# Show that for any $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ with real parts of $a,b$ to be lesser or equals to $0$, one has $|e^b-e^a| \leq |b-a|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that for any $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ with real parts of $a,b$ to be lesser or equals to $0$, one has $$|e^b-e^a| \leq |b-a|$$

Let $a = a_1+ia_2,b=b_1+ib_2$

I have done almost all parts of this proof but I just need one part of the proof to be true to complete the whole question, namely: In my last step, I want to show that $$\frac{2}{2!}-\frac{2(a_2-b_2)^2}{4!}+\frac{2(a_2-b_2)^4}{6!}- \frac{2(a_2-b_2)^6}{8!}...+... \leq 1$$

I forgot how to show this kind of upper bound and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you relate that to the cosine function?

Comment: Yes I can, but I kinda only see $\cos z = 1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+......$ which looks slightly different and hence cannot deduce it.

Comment: $e^b-e^a=\int^{b}_{a}e^z dz$, and choose the integral curve in the left half plane. Because $e^z$ has primitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $$|e^w|=e^{{\bf Re} \ w}<1$$
$$|e^b-e^a|=|\int_a^b e^z\ dz|=
|\int_0^1e^{a+(b-a)t}(b-a)\ dt|\leq\int_0^1 |e^{a+(b-a)t}|\ |b-a|dt=|b-a|$$
where ${\bf Re} \ (a+(b-a)t)<0$.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{b}-e^{a}=(b-a)\int_I e^{tb+(1-t)a} \, dt$ where $I=[0,1]$. [ Because $(b-a) e^{tb+(1-t)a}$ is the derivative of $ e^{tb+(1-t)a}$].  Hence $|e^{b}-e^{a}| \leq (b-a)\int_I e^{\Re (tb+(1-t)a)} \, dt \leq (b-a)$